Evaluating Event Sourcing Strategies: Transitioning from On-Premise Elasticsearch to Azure-Based Solutions
Background
We are building an event-driven system where microservices generate and consume events via an Azure Event Hub. Currently, we store these events in Elasticsearch (v7.10.2) hosted on virtual machines. This approach keeps the data in-house and allows us to query events efficiently, achieving response times of 200ms–300ms.
As part of our cloud adoption strategy, we have decided to migrate our event storage to Azure Services to leverage the scalability and integration capabilities of the cloud.
Current Requirements

Volume: Approximately 50 million events annually.
Query Performance: The new storage solution should match or improve upon Elasticsearch's
query performance (200ms–300ms).
Read/Write Intensive: Our microservices depend heavily on historical event data for both read
and write operations.
Structured Data: The events are stored in a structured format.
Future Scalability: In the long term, we aim to use these events for data processing and AI integration.

Challenges and Attempts

We tested SQL Server, and it performed reasonably well for queries. However, concerns include:

Handling write-heavy workloads as we plan to migrate over a year's worth of historical data.
Indexing for improved query performance might impact write speeds significantly.


Azure Elasticsearch Service

Azure’s managed Elasticsearch seemed like a natural choice, given our existing experience.
However, feedback and reviews about its performance and scalability for similar workloads left us uncertain about its suitability.


Azure Blob Storage

Blob storage was considered due to its cost-effectiveness and scalability.
The major limitation here is the lack of efficient querying capabilities. While Blob tags are supported, they have constraints on the number of tags per blob, making it impractical for extensive querying.



Questions for the Community
Based on our requirements and challenges, what would be the most suitable storage solution on Azure? Should we consider:

A managed NoSQL database like Azure Cosmos DB (using APIs like Table, Cassandra, or MongoDB)?
A hybrid approach with Azure Data Lake for archival and Azure SQL or other NoSQL databases for hot data?
Any other Azure-native service that aligns with our needs?


I would consider separating writes from Reads / Reporting, as keeping all in the same database will cause pain when scaling. (Ie. CQRS approach).
